# LARAVEL4 because it does not reflect the changes to the file in the browser

Tags: laravel

I am creating an application in laravel 4 and these last days did not have this problem, but currently if, every time I save a file, and F5 in the browser pulse this does not reflect the changes.
The files that I have saved are archivo.blade.php extension.
Someone knows what can be wrong with me because both Chrome as in Firefox

Comment: Blade template are cached by default. Can you try to empty app/storage/views and see if it change something ?

Comment: It' s either what frenus said or some caching on the server side / client side (your browser). Have you tired to empty your local cache?

Comment: I had some issues like this on FF, not in Chrome. It seems to be a browser-ish issue (maybe?), if you instead of reload (cmd+r) just submit the url again it refreshes the way it should. (This solution worked for me on FF). Its pretty weird, and ontop of the weirdness it happened randomly to me.